# Laravel API Authentication (Passport) - Password Grant Tokens - Revoking the token

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

I setup Laravel's 5.4 Passport, like the doc [Password Grant Tokens](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#password-grant-tokens), to be consume by mobile and web application.

The problem is, when it's authenticated by **mobile app**, it revokes the token, so the **web app** cann't continue using the same token. 
The same case when I authenticate through the **web app**, the **mobile app** stops being authenticated by the same token.

Is it possible to use this type o grant token to consume this kind of authentication in this scenario?